# Insert value at position X

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I would like to add HTML on to a page once it finds particular text. I have managed to get the position I just can figure out how to add text

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var position = document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf('Gas');

        //insert HTML at position 

    })
```

Answer (score 1):

So since you already know where to insert, just do

```
var str = element.innerHtml;
element.innerHTML = str.substr(0, position - 1) + "<b>My HTML</b>" + str.substr(position);
```

---

Other way it would be to wrap that text in some element and do `.insertBefore()`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var text = $('.my-text').html();
  $('.my-text').html(text.replace(/Gas/, '<span id="my-unique-id">Gas</span>'));
  
  var htmlToInsert = $('<b>', {text: 'Inserted text'});
  htmlToInsert.insertBefore('#my-unique-id');
  $('#my-unique-id').unwrap();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-text">
  Abc def Gas Mesa Bas Ras
</div>
```

Comment: Theres a + missing